# Keras validation loss from model.fit() not expected

Tags: deep-learning, keras

On training my network using model.fit() in Keras with loss='mean_squared_error' in model.compile():

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(decay=0.00001), metrics=['accuracy'])
hist=model.fit(X, Y, epochs=200, batch_size=2000,  verbose=2, shuffle="batch", validation_data=(Xval,Yval))
```

I get this at the end:

> Epoch 200/200 23s - loss: 1.2060 - acc: 0.5168 - val_loss: 1.5213 -
>   val_acc: 0.5294

Now if I manually check the loss on the validation set by

```
pre=model.predict(Xval)
print(np.mean(np.square(pre-Yval)))
```

I get 1.4587 and not 1.5213.

Why are they different? Why am I not getting 1.5213 as calculated by model.fit()? Am I missing something here? Doesn't model.fit() go through the entire validation set?

Comment: Well, you actually got a lower loss value, why are you not happy with that?

Comment: That's true. But shouldn't val_loss reported by `model.fit()` match the loss that I calculate manually?

Comment: Maybe you are not calculating the *same* way Keras does with the loss metric you chose

Comment: Exactly. How else can you calculate mean squared loss?

Comment: I suggest you look at the source code of the 'losses' file, where you can see how they implement mse loss. Keras calls 'k.mean' and 'k.square' from their backend, not sure if they are the same as Numpy's. Anyways looking at the code could give you a better insight of that. However, I suspect the reason is other, and I exposed it in an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

After analyzing this situation I think I know why you could be experiencing this. Judging by the output you get on your epoch `200`, we can see that your model metrics at *that moment* were:

> **loss:** 1.2060 - **acc:** 0.5168 - **val_loss:** 1.5213 - **val_acc:** 0.5294

This means that on that last epoch, the feed-forward model you are training obtained a loss of `1.2060` (and a validation one of `1.5213`).

However, the training algorithm **still has to back-propagate that final loss to update your model weights**. Only after *iterating over inputs*, then calculating *metrics*, and finally *back-propagate* weights, is that an epoch is considered to "end". The same process continues for any additional epochs.

That is why you get different losses when you evaluate after that final epoch, as your model changed a bit after that last back-propagation updated your model, *learning* a bit more than on the previous step. This would also explain why you obtained a lower loss value after epoch `200`, as your model had one more epoch of successful training.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two reasons for it:

1. Output of your network is a vector while `mse` assumes that the output and target outputs are scalers. It would still work with vectors but the values are not reliable.
2. You used a `batch_size` of 2000 during training while during prediction, the `batch_size` is 1. Try `model.predict(Xval,batch_size=256)`. This will make sure that the conditions for the two are the same.

Comment: I tried changing batch_sizes in `model.predict()`. The val loss is still the same.

Comment: Did you try the first option as well?